# Php fetched img urls. How to re-display them online?

Tags: php, arrays, fetch

I'm halfway through figuring out a little project of mine, where I basically fetch a page's images, and then redisplay them on another site of mine. While I'm doing this for purposes of displaying random images of my artwork (won't waste your time explaining the details), I'll use the following example because it basically will do exactly what I'm attempting to do.

Right now what I'm able to do is fetch all image links from a given page, but I don't know how to re-display them as images on a website. Currently the data I get looks like this (test I did): http://www.wilsonschlamme.com/wiki.php

```
Array

(
[0] => https ://kfjhiakwhefkiujahefawef/awoefjoiwejfowe.jpg

[1] => https ://oawiejfoiaewjfoajfeaweoif/awoeifjao;iwejfoawiefj.png

)
```

*fyi as you can see, on the link the urls/file names are different each time. But it still successfully pulls the file names!

*in case you're curious as to where I'm pulling the img information from, it's a nice little wiki random img generator: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File

So that's pretty cool, happy to get this far because I'm very new to PHP. But what I now need to do, is RE display the FIRST image the array picks up, which is img 0. If you're wondering why I'm going through this headache, it has to do with random images, I'm going to be dealing with them, so naturally I need the site to pick up whatever image it finds, regardless of file name.

So likewise, I'm thinking perhaps I replace the code in this current php I'm working with that is displaying this array in text format on the above test link, and instead have some code that takes [0] array, and displays that as an actual image instead, in other words pulls the image from that link, like a < img src="https://_____

How to do that exactly is where I'm lost.

Any thoughts? Thanks so much for reading this. -Wilson

The PHP code that's doing this:

```
<?php
/*
Credits: Bit Repository
URL: http://www.bitrepository.com/
*/

$url = 'http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:Random/File';

// Fetch page
$string = FetchPage($url);

// Regex that extracts the images (full tag)
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.

'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';

preg_match_all($image_regex, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$img_tag_array = $out[0];

echo "<pre>"; print_r($img_tag_array); echo "</pre>";

// Regex for SRC Value
$image_regex_src_url = '/<img[^>]*'.

'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';

preg_match_all($image_regex_src_url, $string, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$images_url_array = $out[1];

echo "<pre>"; print_r($images_url_array); echo "</pre>";

// Fetch Page Function

function FetchPage($path)
{
$file = fopen($path, "r"); 

if (!$file)
{
exit("The was a connection error!");
} 

$data = '';

while (!feof($file))
{
// Extract the data from the file / url

$data .= fgets($file, 1024);
}
return $data;
}




for($i=0; $i<count($arr1); $i++) {
echo '<img src="'.$arr1[$i].'">';
}

?>
```